# Cannot form binding with ItemsControl inside ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, xbind

In a UWP app, I'm attempting to inject a ListBox into a Content Control.  As you will see from the code I'm submitting, the ListBox's ItemsSource binding doesn't register with the PropertyChanged event, thus when I try to change the ItemsSource to a new collection, it doesn't reflect visually in the list.  I know the references are correct because if I create the new collection first before I set the binding, the screen shows the list.  What do I need to do to make the following code work?

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind MyRootControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace App2
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyRootControl, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = myData, Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
            myData = new ObservableCollection<string>(new[] { "hello", "world" });
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(myData)));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> myData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ListBox MyRootControl { get; set; } = new ListBox();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a class derived from DependencyObject. Instead, `myData` should be a dependency property. Currently, myData isn't even a property, but only a field, and hence does not support data binding. Besides that, it's unclear what you are trying to do with it at all.

Comment: @Clemens.  Apologies, there were a couple egregious oversights when attempting to condense the problem to this simple code example.  I have corrected these issues in the original question, which still stands.  I'm trying to understand why changing the ListBox collection doesn't reflect in the content control as it is written.  Converting to a dependency property wouldn't answer this question.

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged still doesn't make sense here. Besides that, firing the PropertyChanged event with the property name "myData" has no effect here, because you've set up your binding incorrectly. `Binding.Source` should be the object that owns the property (`this`), and `Binding.Path` should be set to `new PropertyPath("myData")`.

Comment: @Clemens...  That did it!  Painfully obvious as it sits before me now, lol.  Can you please put                 BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyRootControl, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path= new PropertyPath("myData"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
 as your answer and I'll mark it answered?

Comment: To further justify this example, the original problem uses a viewmodel that doesn't derive from DependencyObject, and uses INotifyPropertyChanged to facilitate bindings, ergo this Occam's

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clemens, who deserves credit for this answer.  The binding syntax was incorrect.  It should be

```
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyRootControl, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = this, Path= new PropertyPath("myData"), Mode = BindingMode.OneWay });
```